# Is the API still the REST API if my URLs are not resourceful?

Tags: laravel, rest, django-rest-framework

In my app, I have admin endpoints. URLs like:

- `http://example.com/api/admin/customers`
- `http://example.com/api/admin/orders`
- `http://example.com/api/admin/movies`

These URIs have GET/POST/DELETE/PUT methods which mean this is the REST API.

Now, after some day, it turned out I made new API URL like the following: `http://example.com/api/regular/rate_movie`. I made this API because there was no gain making it resourceful. So I called it `rate_movie` which is a POST request.

In my app, I have many resourceful API URIs like the above and also I have so many URIs that are not resourceful and each of them is only for themselves, like `/admin/get_admin`,  `/user/store_movie`.

Is my API still called RESTful API or did it die after I made different kind of API URLs?

Comment: Add public keyword before api keyword in url like--
>http://example.com/public/api/admin/customers

Answer (score 1):

Those additional API endpoints you describe seem to follow an RPC (remote procedure call) style. Therefore it could be misleading to refer to the overall API as RESTful.

That's not necessarily an issue if it's a small project or it's just you working on the codebase. If others are involved you might highlight the REST and RPC endpoints, perhaps noting where the differences styles are used in your code or docs.

Comment: and why would they be rpc? Those other apis are also post,get,delete.  They're just called different name conventions.

Comment: "rate movie" is a phrasal verb which implies the server (a _remote_ program) will perform an action (run a _procedure_) when requested (like a function _call_). The redundancy between the HTTP verb and the verb implied by the endpoint name was considered undesirable and was one of the motivations for developing the ReST style.

Comment: let's call it /rates. what difference does it make ? only url changes.

Comment: Changing the URL may impact how easy it is to understand and work with your API. Beyond that... yeah it doesn't really make much difference. This all starts to get to the fundamental principles behind the REST architectural style. I'd suggest checking out Roy's dissertation to appreciate the rationale behind it.

Comment: they do seem like rpc calls because the function is encoded in the url (rate_movie). If it was "pure" REST, it would be http://example.com/api/regular/movie/rating/ with GET,PUT,POST,DELETE for a "movie rating" resource. So if you wanted to rate a movie, you would POST rating JSON (for example) to the "movie rating" resource. So rather than exposing everything you can do to a movie as a separate url, you would expose "REST" endpoints for every attribute of a movie, e.g. "rating" and use REST verbs on those endpoints.

Comment: 1) rate_movie is not a function. It's just what I call the url.  2) I named it because I only have post request which would store rating. no getting or deleting at all.